# what is the macro used for in a vtkobject?

Tags: c++, c++11, vtk

what is macro used for in a vtkobject?
[example](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Developers/vtkObject)

```
vtkStandardNewMacro(vtkLidarPoint);
```

And why is the constructor static?

```
static vtkLidarPoint *New();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a constructor. It's a factory method.

The macro looks like it just implements the factory method. See [here](http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/vtkObjectFactory_8h.html#a53278154168dc7128e1376a0df8d4002).